# Issue with stringstream/osstream not chaining << operator and never calling flush at std::end

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

So I have the following logging class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

struct asDigest {
    explicit asDigest(const void* text, size_t len) : _t(text), _l(len) {}
    explicit asDigest(const std::string& text) : _t(text.c_str()), _l(text.size(){}
    const void* _t;
    size_t _l;
};

struct asPointer {
    explicit asPointer(const char* _p) : p(_p) {}
    const char* p;
};

class Diagnostics
{
private:
    std::stringstream  m_stream;
    std::string        m_tag;
public:
    typedef std::ostream&  (*ManipFn)(std::ostream&);
    typedef std::ios_base& (*FlagsFn)(std::ios_base&);
    Diagnostics(const std::string& str) : m_tag(str) {}

    template<class T>  // int, double, strings, etc
    std::ostream& operator<<(const T& output)
    {
        m_stream << output;
        return m_stream;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(ManipFn manip) /// endl, flush, setw, setfill, etc.
    {
        manip(m_stream);

        if (manip == static_cast<ManipFn>(std::flush)
            || manip == static_cast<ManipFn>(std::endl ) ) {
            this->flush();
        }

        return m_stream;
    }

    Diagnostics& operator<<(FlagsFn manip) /// setiosflags, resetiosflags
    {
        manip(m_stream);
        return *this;
    }

    Diagnostics& operator()(std::string& e)
    {
        m_tag = e;
        return *this;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(struct asPointer ptr)
    {
        m_stream << "0x" << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << reinterpret_cast<const unsigned long long*>(ptr.p) << std::dec;
        return m_stream;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(struct asDigest dgst)
    {
        m_stream << std::string("Test Digest");
        return m_stream;
    }

    void flush()
    {
        /*
         MAKE CALL TO OS LOG HERE
        */
        m_stream.str( std::string() );
        m_stream.clear();
    }
};
```

The intended usage is as follows:

```
Diagnostics("TAG") << "Message" << "MoreMessages" << std::endl
```

I can create an instance of the logger, the tag is set and upon hitting the breakpoint set on `std::ostream& operator<<(const T& output)` I can see that the first string is fed into the stream. I am struggling however because nothing else seems to happen, the same method is never called for subsequent strings and `flush()` is never called so I can't read the entire stream.

I have a feeling I'm missing something here or I have misunderstood the APIs. Any assistance to achieve what I'm looking for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Diagnostics("TAG") << "Message"` returns an `ostream&` reference to the internal `m_stream`, so subsequent `... << "MoreMessages" << std::endl` will go directly to that stream, bypassing all of your class's logic.

To chain your `operator<<`s correctly, they all need to return `Diagnostics&` instead of `ostream&`, replacing `return m_stream;` with `return *this;` (your `operator<<(FlagsFn)` and `operator()` are already doing this), eg:

```cpp
template<class T>  // int, double, strings, etc
Diagnostics& operator<<(const T& output)
{
    m_stream << output;
    return *this;
}

Diagnostics& operator<<(ManipFn manip) /// endl, flush, setw, setfill, etc.
{
    manip(m_stream);

    if (manip == static_cast<ManipFn>(std::flush)
        || manip == static_cast<ManipFn>(std::endl ) ) {
        this->flush();
    }

    return *this;
}

Diagnostics& operator<<(FlagsFn manip) /// setiosflags, resetiosflags
{
    manip(m_stream);
    return *this;
}

Diagnostics& operator()(std::string& e)
{
    m_tag = e;
    return *this;
}

Diagnostics& operator<<(struct asPointer ptr)
{
    m_stream << "0x" << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << reinterpret_cast<const unsigned long long*>(ptr.p) << std::dec;
    return *this;
}

Diagnostics& operator<<(struct asDigest dgst)
{
    m_stream << "Test Digest";
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly I did this on my first run, however I got a build failure with the error `Use of overloaded operator << is ambiguous (with operand types Logger::Diagnostics' and (anonymous namespace)::asPointer)` I assume it is something to do with `asPointer` existing in another un-named namespace. But I couldn't fix the error.

Comment: @DannyBoi8181 [works fine for me](https://ideone.com/XAtPvO). I would suggest moving `asDigest` and `asPointer` as nested types inside of the `Diagnostics` class, though ([demo](https://ideone.com/zqKpCo))